# ResourceException while moving resources

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Problems encountered while moving resources. When a user renames the file `file.job`, Related to this file two more files (`file.xml` and `file.properties`) are there.

But when a user renames `file.job`, I get an exception saying that:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException:-   
Problems encountered while moving resources. 
Description is :-  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

please advise.

Comment: Sounds silly but have you tried killing every related tasks or at the very lest rebooting ?

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message states:

> the file is being used by another process.

You need to find out, which process is using the file and make sure to stop the process from using the file before it is moved.

See here how to find the appropriate process: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)